# Catching exceptions with Xalan xslt

Tags: java, xslt, xalan

I have the folowwing `XSLT` based on `Xalan`:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
XalanErrorListener listener = new XalanErrorListener();
factory.setErrorListener(listener);

// Create transformer
StreamSource config = new StreamSource(xslPath);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(config);

// Create input / ouput
StreamSource source = new StreamSource(inputPath);
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outputPath);

// Transform
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

My `XalanErrorListener` simply overrides `error`, `fatalError` and `warning` methods from the `javax.xml.transform.ErrorListener` class and logs the exception:

```
public final class XalanErrorListener implements ErrorListener {

static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XalanErrorListener.class);

@Override
public void error(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
    LOGGER.error(exception);
}

@Override
public void fatalError(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
    LOGGER.error(exception);
}

@Override
public void warning(TransformerException exception) throws TransformerException {
    LOGGER.warn(exception);
}
}
```

Yet, when executing on a badly encoded file, I get the following message in the console:

```
(Location of error unknown)
  com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.io.MalformedByteSequenceException: 
    Invalid byte 2 of 2-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

The program executes normally: no exception is thrown or logged and the generated file is empty!

How can I catch the exception to handle it the way I want?

Comment: So `XalanErrorListener ` is a class you have written? If so, you must show that class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem came from the fact that the `ErrorListener` needed to be set to the `Transformer` and not the `TransformerFactory`:

```
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(config);
transformer.setErrorListener(listener);
```

Comment: If the exception is happening during newTransformer, I don't understand how setting a listener on the transformer after the fact will allow an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The ErrorListener you supply to Xalan catches transformation errors, but it does not catch XML parsing errors. For that you need to supply an ErrorHandler to the Xerces parser.

Comment: Supply the input to the transformation as a SAXSource; create the XMLReader in the SAXSource yourself; initialize its ErrorHandler property.